# Tool, which can find out wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I am looking for a tool, which can find out if a website is written with Wordpress. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an online tool-website for that purpose - visit "isitwp dot com". It should tell you is wordpress used in the website you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I use `Wappalyzer` which is a browser extension. It's a super useful tool

Answer (score 0):

You can also manually check a site to see if it's built on WordPress.

1. Right click on the page and select "Inspect Element"
2. Then open the `<head></head>` and look for the tag `<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 5.4.2">`